# Docusign migration from Legacy to OAuth 2.0 Authentication

Tags: docusignapi

I have been researching back and forth also talking to Docusign support but nobody can help me.   We area still using the legacy authentication.

We need help how to switch to the new OAuth authentication.   We are using Visual Studio 2015 Community, .NetFramework 4.5 and Docusign.dll SDK Version 4.0.4.   I understand that our system is too old and have not catch up to the new versions.   Take Note:  We are not using Console program, not using a Project but we are using a Web Based Application c#.   I just installed the new Visual Studio 2022, installed the Docusign SDK version 4.5.2 from the Nuget package manager, and upgraded to .NET framework 4.5.2.   Again just a reminder, we are not using Visual Studio Core.   We are not using Console program or any project.   We are in a website development where a user pushes a button, that creates a pdf file manually, and sends the pdf file to Docusign for our customers to sign and date.

This is the Legacy Authentication that we have:

```
            if (!Configuration.Default.DefaultHeader.ContainsKey("X-DocuSign-Authentication"))
            {
                string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";
                Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
            }
```

I tried to download the JWT-console program from Docusign and it works.  But when I transferred just using the initial code below, we have some errors:

```
    OAuthToken accessToken = null;
    try
    {
        accessToken = JWTAuth.AuthenticateWithJWT("ESignature", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonatedUserId"],
                                                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthServer"], DSHelper.ReadFileContent(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PrivateKeyFile"]));

    }
```

1st error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUWzS.png)

and a bunch of errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g94JN.png)

Please help how can we migrate the Legacy Authentication to our webpage using Visual Studio.

Thank you

I already called and emailed tech support, until now no answers.

Comment: Ok there is a little bit of progress, I created a Visual Studio MVC5, errors like convert c# 5 to c# 6 gone away, all other errors too disappeared, it looks like i'm on the right track, but there is an error says "CONSENT_REQUIRED".   Here is the code below that I added in my MVC controller:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer from a Docusign Tech support and he was able to help me replacing my code to the new one below.   We will remain to use VS 2015 and Docusign Ver. 4.0.4 below.   We can't make upgrades yet but we will in the near future.

```
        string basePath = "";
        if (bDebug)
        {
            basePath = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";
        }
        else
        {
            basePath = "https://www.docusign.net/restapi";
        }

        var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
        string privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----XXXXX-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n";
        OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken("integrator key goes here", "user id goes here", "account-d.docusign.com", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(privateKey), 600, new List<string> { "signature", "impersonation" });
        var token = authToken.access_token;            

        Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("Authentication", token);
        Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your version of Visual Studio, so you can upgrade your versions of C# and versions of .NET

We support VS 2019 or VS 2022
We support .NET version 4.6.2 or above, see here - https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll

Comment: Hello, I just upgraded from .NET framework 4.5.2 to 4.7.2, upgraded Docusign.eSign.dll from ver 4.5.2 to 6.5.0 and still the same errors.  Here are the errors:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUWzS.png
and 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g94JN.png

Comment: This error still shows the project is version 4.5.2, do you have multiple projects? did you confirm you updated project .NET version?

Comment: CONSENT REQUIRED is a one time issue to give consent, there are lots of resources about this https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/

Comment: Ok the consent required is fixed, i did a one time allow access then i saw the access token.   Question though, is it a best way to integrate this MVC app that it only does is to give tokens to my web app that as soon i get the token from the mvc, then i can go ahead and email the pdf for signing?

Comment: you can either email or it can be embedded on your app, both options. As for the token, you should have the code in your app, maybe use 2 projects if you must use lower version project too

Comment: If you have further questions please open new questions here, it's hard to answer on the comments without all the information